# why OnceLock doesn't accept std::sync::mpsc::Receiver as generic parameter

Tags: rust

Why `OnceLock` doesn't accept `std::sync::mpsc::Receiver` as generic parameter.

```
use std::sync::{mpsc, OnceLock};

static CELL: OnceLock<mpsc::Receiver<Vec<u8>>> = OnceLock::new();

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Error

```
error[E0277]: `std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<Vec<u8>>` cannot be shared between threads safely
 --> src/main.rs:3:14
  |
3 | static CELL: OnceLock<mpsc::Receiver<Vec<u8>>> = OnceLock::new();
  |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<Vec<u8>>` cannot be shared between threads safely
  |
  = help: the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<Vec<u8>>`
  = note: required for `OnceLock<std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<Vec<u8>>>` to implement `Sync`
  = note: shared static variables must have a type that implements `Sync`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

Comment: This is not about the `OnceLock`, this is about `static`. `mpsc::Receiver` is not `Sync`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman then the only option I have is to use `Mutex` instead of `OnceLock`. Am I correct?

Comment: Or much better, use a MPMC channel.